# Passing a parameter to a python function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to use Parse Cloud Code to run a python script. I'm passing a parameter, but I seem to be getting an error. I'm not 100% sure what the problem is, but it seems like I'm not composing the url correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

My python code looks like this:

```
# a function that makes a sentence more exciting
def excited(sentence):
   return sentence + '!!!'
```

Here's my code in main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('testFunction', function(request, response) {
    var someParam = request.params['testString'];
    var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/test.py/excited&sentence=' + someParam;
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.headers);
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success();
        }, error: function(httpResponse, error) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the output you see? What is the parameter you are passing?

Comment: The parameter is ```'Hello World'```. The output is: ```Error: success/error was not called (Code: 11, Version: 1.7.5)```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

Now I understand the problem better.
You are trying to call a python method from Parse.Cloud javascript based service. Based on their tutorials, I think you probably wanted the other way round.

Parse.Cloud allows you to deploy some server-side code in javascript. Then you can make REST API calls from your mobile app to the server endpoints by using either python or curl or any other language or tool. While testing, you can just call the end points from python on your box.

So your server code (in cloud/main.js) should look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testFunction", function(request, response) {
  var excitedSentence = request.params.testString + "!!!";
  response.success(excitedSentence);
});
```

This code creates a REST API endpoint at https://api.parse.com/1/functions/testFunction

Then you can call this API endpoint by using python (assuming you have Python installed on your box):

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/functions/testFunction', json.dumps({
       "testString": "This is an example sentence"
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "xxxxx_PUT_YOUR_ID_xxxxxxx",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "xxxxxxxx_YOUR_KEY_xxxxxx",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

If you don't have python installed, you can call the API endpoint by going to the online dashboard.

1. Go to: Your App -> Core tab -> API Console.
2. For endpoint, select post (this is important), and specify "functions/testFunction" in the text box.
3. In request body, specify: {"testString" : "This is an example sentence"}
4. Click "Send Request" and you should see the following output:

   ```
   "result": "This is an example sentence!!!"
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks turbo, just tried it but still getting the same error response.

Comment: What if you add a response.error call after the console.error line. response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status); Check out [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/successerror-functions-not-getting-called-even-with-simple-example).

Comment: Nice catch. I'm now seeing: Request failed with response code 404 (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.5)

Comment: 404 (Not found). Does test.py exist? (I am not very familiar with Cloud.Parse, I am just looking from python side.). Does Cloud.Parse actually require you to specify the filename? To help debug, you might want to remove the param and just stick to printing something static in method excited, like 'return "hi"'. If you get that working, url param should be easier to add.

Comment: Ahh yupp, it seems like the url should end at test.py. I guess the problem is knowing how to send the param over.